# get Aggregate Query Result in the Template File (Handlebars)

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, handlebars.js

```
    var agg = [
  {$group: {
    _id: null,
    totalPrice: { $sum: "$itemPrice" }, 
    total: {$sum: 1}
  }}
];
Idea.aggregate(agg, function(err, logs){
  if (err) { 
    return def.reject(err); 
  }
  console.log(logs);
});
```

and here it is the template file

```
    {{#each ideas}}
  <div class="card card-body mb-2">

    <h4>{{title}}</h4>
    <p>{{details}}</p>
    <a class="btn btn-dark btn-block mb-2" href="/ideas/edit/{{id}}">Edit</a>
    <form method="post" action="/ideas/{{id}}?_method=DELETE">
      <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" value="Delete">
    </form>
  </div>
{{else}}
  <p>No video ideas listed</p>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: What is the question? I don't even see that you are even sending the data to render in the template. Lots of existing answers here showing you how to iterate an array with handlebars.

Comment: i just want to show the answer from aggregate query in the template file. 
like i have write the query of sum that gives me answer in console but when i try to get it in a variable to show in html file it give nothing.